# How to mock the get function from requests.session?

Tags: python, django, mocking, python-requests

I am trying to mock the get function from `requests.session` and somehow it does not end up happening.

I have the following code:

```
#main.py
import requests

def function_with_get():

    c = requests.session()

    c.get('https://awesome_url.com')

    # do some other stuff

    return c

def second_function_with_get(client):
    c.get('https://awesome_url.com')

    # do some other stuff


#test.py
from unittest import mock
from django.test import TestCase

class Testing(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('main.requests.session.get)
    @mock.patch('main.requests.session)
    def test_which_fails_because_of_get(mock_sess, mock_get):
        client = function_with_get()
        second_function_with_get(client)

        assertEqual(mock_requests_session_get.call_count, 2)
```

The test throws an assertion error that `mock_get` is called 0 times (`0 != 2`)

How should the `get` function of `requests.session()` be mocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are already mocking the requests session - since it is a `MagicMock`, you don't need to additionally mock the get method itself - checking for calls on the session will be enough.

So, your test.py could look like this:

```py
#test.py
from unittest import mock
from unittest import TestCase

from main import function_with_get, second_function_with_get


class Testing(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('main.requests.session')
    def test_which_fails_because_of_get(self, mock_sess):
        client = function_with_get()
        second_function_with_get(client)

        self.assertEqual(mock_sess.return_value.get.call_count, 2)
```

You could also try to create your own `SessionMock` class with the `get` method mocked, but it would require also proper setting (or resetting) it for each test. Personally, I usually find using MagicMock and its `return_value` chain easier.